# What Format should FormData have?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, form-data

so I want to upload the `test` JSON to arweave. The appending of `transaction` and `env` works fine, but when I try to append bufferTest I get this error

`Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Failed to execute 'append' on 'FormData': parameter 2 is not of type 'Blob'.`

I tried doing: `data.append('file[]', new Blob(bufferTest), 'metadata.json');`, but then it just uploads the Buffer values in UTF8 like this: `1.2334116101115117e+39`.
I literally just copied this from Metaplex candy-machine-v2. They also just append the Buffer.
I don't know if this has something to do with React or me just being stupid.

```
const test = { "test": "test" };
const bufferTest: any = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(test)); //metadata as buffer

export default function Test(props:any){

    //...
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('transaction', txID!); // Transaction ID
    data.append('env', env);  // env = devnet
    data.append('file[]', bufferTest, 'metadata.json');

    const result = await upload(data);
    //...

}
async function upload(data: FormData) {
    return await (
        await fetch(ARWEAVE_UPLOAD_ENDPOINT, {
            method: 'POST',
            // @ts-ignore
            body: data,
        })
    ).json();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to put a for loop on all files selected inside the input file like the bellow :

```
var len = document.getElementById('XXXX').files.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len ; i++) {
    fd.append("file[]", document.getElementById('XXXX').files[i]);
}
```

let me know if it's working

Comment: It's just one file. I don't know why there are square braces (the candy machine code also has it; removing them doesn't change anything) but I just want to upload the 'test' variable which has JSON structure.
So it should just be 'data.append('file', bufferTest, 'metadata.json');'?
Why should I do getElementById?

Comment: Now I just see 'null', the I try to upload a larger JSON object.

Comment: you use document.getElementById in order to get the uploaded file and in the backend you can manipulate it and read the content there